# Paste function not working in title of shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to add some text to the current title in shiny app. So
I used

```
paste("Hello Shiny!", textOutput("text1"))
```

in the title but unfortunately something is wrong. The output and R code are as follows:

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    title=
    #textOutput("text1")#
    paste("Hello Shiny!", textOutput("text1")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1<-renderText({"Title changed dynamically"})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste the data on the server side -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    title= textOutput("text1"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text1<-renderText({
    dynamic_title <- "Title changed dynamically"
    paste("Hello Shiny!", dynamic_title)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]